# Refresh list after item is created

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

On Angular 7 I have the following component (some code omited for sake of simplicity):

```
export class CreatePostComponent {

  form: FormGroup;

  onSubmit() {
    this.postService.create(request).subscribe(
      (response) => { this.form.reset();},
      (error) => { }
    );
  }
}
```

When this form is successfully submitted I need to refresh a list of post which is handled by the component:

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  posts$: Observable<PostModel[]>;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.posts$ = this.getPosts();

  }

  private getPosts(): Observable<PostModel[]> {

  }

}
```

So basically I need to call `getPosts` again ... How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if both components are related with parent-child relationship. If so, this is how I would do it:

```
    export class CreatePostComponent {
      form: FormGroup;
      public refreshPosts: number;
      onSubmit() {
        this.postService.create(request).subscribe(
          (response) => { 
    this.form.reset();
this.refreshPosts = +new Date();
    },
          (error) => { }
        );
      }
    }
```

Now you can pass this refreshPosts property as an input bound property to the PostListComponent:

```
    export class PostListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

@Input() refreshPosts: any
      posts$: Observable<PostModel[]>;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.posts$ = this.getPosts();
      }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.refreshPosts && !changes.refreshPosts.isFirstChange()) {
      this.getPosts();
    }
  }

      private getPosts(): Observable<PostModel[]> {

      }

    }
```

Comment: They are not parent / child. List is a component displaying a template. In the template there is a button that when clicked opens a modal with the CreatePostComponent. So I believe your suggestion won't work. Should I use events?

Comment: What modal you are using. A modal on save or close always returns a result, using that you can refresh your post data. Would be great if you could share stackblitz of your implementation so far?

Comment: I will add a stackblitz example tomorrow. I need to create one from scratch that replicates everything.

Comment: I created a new more concise question with a StackBlitz example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116905/update-list-when-new-item-is-added. Could you please give your feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Good practice would be to transfer both your posts and getPosts() function to your postService. This will work regardless of component hierarchy:

```
private _posts = new BehaviorSubject<PostModel[]>([]);

getPosts() { 
    return this._posts.asObservable(); 
}
```

You fetch the data with a separate function to call your api, then use `.next()` to push the result to `_posts`

```
fetchPosts() {
    // replace with your api, i.e. HttpClient
    someApi.get()
       .then(result => this._posts.next(result))
       .catch(err => { // handle error });
}
```

You can create as many `get()` functions as you want, they will all have the same data source:

```
getRecentPosts() {
    return this._posts.asObservable().pipe(
        filter(post => { // filter logic }),
        map(post => { // map logic })
    )
}
```

Then inside your `postService.create()` function you can manipulate your posts array. In your template you use `postService.getPosts()` to stay up to date.

Comment: There is a problem ... PostService has a GetPosts method that calls an API to get posts and then returns  Observable<PostResponseModel[]. Then each component the calls that service has its own model and maps the PostResponseModel to its PostModel with the properties that it needs. So, I believe your suggestion won't work. Am I correct?

Comment: No problem, inside that api call function, instead of returning the Observable data directly, you call _posts.next() with your api results. I updated my answer

Comment: Still not sure ... What about if you have different method in your service like: getRecentPosts or getTopPosts ... And more than that, each method requests different fields fo a Post from the API. For example, getRecentPosts asks for recentPosts including each post category and tags. But getTopPosts asks only for Post Title and PublishDate from API. Would you have 2 _posts properties in the service?

Comment: Nope, you can create new functions and just use RxJS pipeable operators. Updated answer