# Update list when new item is added

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Using Angular 7 I have the following service ([StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-sync-list)):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TodoService {

  todos: BehaviorSubject<Todo[]> = new BehaviorSubject([
    { id: 1, title: "Buy book", content: "Buy book about angular" },
    { id: 2, title: "Send invoice", content: "Send invoice to client A" }
  ]);

  public get(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.todos.asObservable();
  }

  public create(todo: Todo) {
    this.todos.next(this.todos.value.concat(todo));
  }

}
```

This service is used by a few components:

1. TodoCreateComponent > Creates new todo
2. TodoListComponent > Shows list of todos
3. TodoRecentComponent > Shows recent todos

Each component has its own model mapped from a `Todo` in its own way ...

Some models use many `Todo` properties (`Title`, `Content`), others only one (`Title`) etc.

On my [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-sync-list) a new `Todo` is, automatically, added to the todo list:

**Objective**

Now I need to replace the local data by data taken from an API:

```
public get(): Observable<Todo[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Todo>(`todos`);
}

public create(todo: Todo) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  this.httpClient.post(`todos`, todo, { headers: headers });
}
```

**Question**

The question is how to integrate HttpClient to get everything in sync:

So when a new `Todo` is created the list of `Todos` should be updated ...

Comment: IMO, the best way to handle this is to repoll the server in the subscribe callback of the request that posts the new TODO.

Comment: You mean, on, inside the TodoCreateComponent, on the todoService.create callback call the todoService.get and refill the list with updated data? But how to can TodoCreateComponent access to TodoListComponent to update the list.

Comment: Use a service as described in https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service with one change - add the service in `app.module`'s `providers` array instead of listing the service in the component's `providers` metadata.

Comment: You mean to create a Service, with a property "DataUpdated" and then inject that service in TodoListComponent and TodoCreateComponent? When TodoCreateComponent adds a todo it update that DataUpdated to true and TodoListComponent catches that change and calls the TodoService Get to get update data from API? Is this what you mean? Could you, please, just post a simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a notification service to tell the list component to repoll the server.

```
export class RepollTodosNotificationService {

  subject: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject();
  obs: Observable<any> = this.subject.asObservable;

  notify = (data: any) => {
    this.subject.next(data)
  }
}
```

Make service a singleton:

(app.module.ts)

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [RepollTodosNotificationService]
})
```

In `TodoCreateComponent`

```
this.todoSevice.post(myNewTodo)
     .subscribe(
        result => {
          // current callback code
          this.repollNotifierService.notify(null); // null or data you want to send
```

In `TodoListComponent`

```
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private repollSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private repollSvc: RepollTodosNotificationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.repollSvc.obs.subscribe(() => this.fetchTodos()); // if you transfer data, handle here
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    // methods

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to stay sync is to update your BehaviorSubject upon the response of your API using the RxJS operator `tap`, for example:

```
public get(): Observable<Todo[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Todo>(`todos`)
     .pipe(tap(todo => this.todos.next(todos)))
}
```

or

```
public create(todo): Observable<Todo[]> {
  return this.httpClient.post<Todo>(`apiUrl`, todo)
     .pipe(tap(todo => // do something with the todo ))
}
```

Comment: Not sure I am following ... You are keeping the BehaviorSubject sync but you are always returning the httpClient response? Shouldn't you return "this.todos"?

Comment: One question that seems to be a problem ... imagine that your todoService.get accepts a parameter named "include". So the API can be called using "todos/?include=comments", "todos/?include=comments,reviews". By doing this it is possible to get todos only with basic data or with extra data ... Wouldn't that be a problem? this.todos would have a list of todos but some of them with extra data? Or does tap also fills missing properties on existing todos in this.todos?

Comment: You could pass the parameters as function arguments to be a bit more flexible. You can chain the operators to map the data in whatever way you might need. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/